# Detachment of Autocomplete Box size from input-field width

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

As far as I can see the autocomplete Box of google has always the same width as the input field it belongs to.

```
<input type="text" id="autoTest">

#autoTest{
  width: 40px;
}
```

Result:

[image: Autocomplete 1]

And

```
#autoTest{
  width: 400px;
```

}

Result:

[image: Autocomplete 2]

Is there ANY way to achieve a bigger width, without changing the width of the input field. Because this is in my case no option. It is also not relevant for the user to get the entire Street name displayed within the input field after he has choosen one.

I appreciate a clean solution, but if that is not possible I would also take a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the selector `.pac-container` to apply a custom style to the dropdown:

```js
function initialize() {

  new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autoTest'))
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
.pac-container {
  width: 400px !important;
}
#autoTest {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places">
</script>
<input id="autoTest"/>
```